Why can quantum entanglement not use temporal encoding to transmit information?
It's common knowledge that quantum entanglement can't be used to transmit information; however, I'm struggling to understand why an encoding based on time intervals in which measurements are made wouldn't allow information transfer.
For example, consider two pairs A and B of entangled particles. A measurement of A is made on the messenger's end, and 1 second later a measurement of B is made on the same end. Correspondingly, the receiver learns the state of pair A, and exactly 1 second later learns the state of pair B. The receiver and messenger could have previously agreed that a measurement period of 1 second represents the word "yes", while a period of 2 seconds or longer represents the word "no". This appears to allow information transfer.
What am I missing here?

"The receiver and messenger could have previously agreed that a measurement period of 1 second represents the word "yes", while a proof of 2 seconds or longer represents the word "no". This appears to allow information transfer." This section of your proposed experiment doesn't make sense to me.

"Correspondingly, the receiver learns the state of pair A, and exactly 1 second later learns the state of pair B." How do they do that? There is no measurement that the receiver can make on their A & B particles that will tell them that the sender has measured their A & B particles.

@mike1994 I don't know what it is with StackExchange users and claiming not to understand clear sentences. Truly, I have no clue what part of that simple paragraph puzzles you.

@PM2Ring See my reply to DrChinese's answer, which pointed out the same problem.

The user @mike1994 is absolutely correct: Your explanation makes no sense and it is NOT clear what kind of "protocol" you are suggesting. Also, this and very very similar questions have been asked here a thousand times before...

In general, I'd suggest to be as clear as possible and to provide some (simple) example. Take any Bell-state of two spin-$1/2$ particles in the EPRB set-up. Can you write down what you have in mind for this explicit example? (In doing so, you should also see that according to the framework of QM, $B$'s probability to obtain a specific outcome of a measurement he can perform is the same whether or not $A$ has performed any measurement on her particle. That's the essence of the no-communication theorem.)

@TobiasFünke You have misunderstood what I'm saying. I know the probability of A obtaining a certain outcome isn't affected by B's measurement. However, B's measurement does collapse the wavefunctions of the entangled particles. If A can detect when this collapse takes place, then they gain information about when B made their measurement. This information can be used for communication via temporal encoding.

The ontological status of the wave function is not clear, and the same holds for collapse (note that there are interpretations in which no collapse happens). Also, "collapse" and "wave function" are not oberservable. Anyway, how should $B$ see, with only LOCAL measurements/action whether or not $A$ has performed a measurement? Again, I ask you to show some protocol, formulated in the framework of QM.

@Max The wavefunction isn't a physical wave. It isn't even a function on spacetime as it is a function of both position vectors.

@VincentThacker I've received this explanation multiple times on this thread, but is an interference pattern not a physical thing? It's a direct representation of the superposition of photon states. If the messenger and receiver communicate via an interference pattern formed by entangled photons, they can clearly detect the exact moment of wavefunction collapse: it's when the interference pattern disappears. DrChinese explains that entangled photons don't form classical interference patterns. I imagine the more general rule is that entangled particles don't form observable superpositions.

The receiver learns information only by observing, making a measurement. That’s a one shot opportunity. All the receiver will see upon measuring is a series of random bits. Not much information to be seen in that.
Now, it is possible to vary the timing of the bits sent to the receiver so a message is encoded. This is classical communication, so naturally it is limited to the speed of light. And you don’t need entangled pairs to accomplish this.
Note that entangled particles do not, of themselves, indicate whether or not its partner has yet been measured. If both particles are measured in the same manner, the information each party receives is redundant (as compared to the other party). The results do not vary in any observable manner based on order of measurement.

Edited to add: You can't observe a particle as being in a superposition. When you make the measurement, you get a specific value.  You'd expect that, right? So you can't from that measurement alone determine if it previously had that specific value, some other specific value, or was instead in a superposition. Yes, you might deduce it was in a superposition in some cases; but no experiment actually could tell you as much.

Edited a second time to consider an often asked related question: Why can't you use a double slit setup on both of an entangled pair; then have one (Alice) do a which slit observation which should then collapse the other (Bob) - which would eliminate Bob's interference pattern; thus allowing Alice to control what Bob sees; which would be an FTL signaling mechanism?
This won't work because: Entangled particles do not form standard single particle interference patterns in the first place, so Alice's actions will not change anything for Bob.  The full reasons are outside the context of the OP, but the short version is that entangled particles are not coherent.  See for example Zeilinger (1999) Experiment and the foundations of quantum physics.  Figure 2 discusses this exact situation.
PS Zeilinger shared the Nobel in 2022 for his many incredible contributions, mostly around entanglement (both experiment and theory).  If you are interested in entanglement but are not familiar with all of the ideas he presents in this 9 page summary, then I  would label this a must-read.

This is the answer that should be cited any time someone comes up with a new entanglement experiment to communicate faster than light! My knowledge over here that you are going to measure spin down when I measured spin up does not allow us to say anything to each other.

"Note that entangled particles do not, of themselves, indicate whether or not its partner has yet been measured". So if the messenger has already measured A, will the receiver still see A as being in superposition until they make their own measurement? Intuitively, this is pretty strange as, once the entangled system A is measured, the wavefunction of both of its constituent particles should have collapsed.

Let's stick with spin as the observable. If the messenger measures their particle and see's that it is spin up, they can be certain that the receiver will measure spin down, so yes, it is no longer in a superposition. But the receiver is not going to see a "collapsed wavefunction", they are simply going to measure a particle with spin down. The wavefunction itself is not observable. If I measure an electron to have some property, all I know is that the electron had that property at that time. I myself am totally ignorant to what the wavefunction looked like beforehand.

@Max "will the receiver still see A as being in superposition until they make their own measurement?" The receiver can't see anything about A without making some kind of measurement on it.

@PM2Ring I was thinking of the double-slit experiment. The interference pattern of light can be observed without making making a measurement on which slit the individual photons passed through. Let's say there are two beams of light which are entangled: it is known that if one beam passes through one slit, the other must pass through the other. And let's say the messenger observes a photon from one of the beams. Well the receiver see an interference pattern until they themselves observe one of the beams?

@Max When you make the measurement, you get a specific value, right? You can't from that alone determine if it previously had that specific value, or was instead in a superposition. I edited my answer to add this point.

@Max Your question about the Double Slit is very logical. As you might expect, nature doesn't allow that since that technique could be used for FTL communication. This comment is not the place to go into the details, but the short answer is that entangled photons do not produce DS interference patterns. See this excellent article from a Nobel winner, Figure 2: https://courses.washington.edu/ega/more_papers/zeilinger.pdf

@DrChinese Interesting. This paper, however (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-68181-1), claims a two-photon interference pattern is indeed produced by path-entangled photons, and that indeed this pattern disappears when the path of one of the photons is observed. How do you reconcile that with what you're saying in your comment?

@Max Good work finding this reference. I did say these comments are not the place to go into detail, and my answer was the short one (due to complexity of the subject). From the paper, Figure 4: “ There is no interference exhibited by the individual photons as shown by single photon counts of single photon detectors D1 and D2.” Only when classical signals are  used for coincidence counting of entangled pairs does a “hidden” pattern reveal itself. The reason is in the paper too: “a single photon amplitude is completely incoherent” - coherence is required for the DS. Ask a brand new question?

@DrChinese I see. So if we refer back to the scenario I describe in the original question, why will the receiver not be able to see the hidden interference pattern? Or is it that this pattern doesn't collapse instantaneously on both ends but rather the collapse travels at the speed of light?

@Max The receiver sees no interference on his own, as also shown on figure 4 of your reference (top arched line). The pattern only appears when the sender’s results are sent to the receiver, which requires a classical signal from the sender - thus defeating our FTL scheme. As to collapse (assuming it occurs): if it is not instantaneous, it has been experimentally shown to be at least 10,000 times the speed of light. Also, note that your reference is not a typical double slit setup. There are a number of experiments showing 2 photon interference, including the well known Hong-Ou-Mandel type.

@DrChinese Ah, that makes sense. Interesting how close entanglement can come to violating the non-communication theorem. I would tick your answer if you could edit in a summary of what you've explained in this comment thread.

@Max I edited my answer to add some about your June 2 comment/follow-up question, and my response. I also added a great reference that discusses the exact setup you envision. I hope you will study this, the concepts presented are a must for understanding entanglement. I hope this helps.
